# RedirectStandard Output/Error wont call my event for Standard Output/Error

Tags: c#, httplistener

hi i'm trying to build a parser for my System to Manage my Tekkit Server i am using C# but i have RedirectStandardOutput on my Tekkit Server process and there is a method set-up to then send that output to my console after adding to a List but it's not adding to a `List<string>`

Here is my code:

```
public void StartServer(string maxMem, string minMem, string path)
{
    ThreadStart server = new ThreadStart(delegate() { StartServerThread(maxMem, minMem, path); });
    server.Invoke();
}

private void StartServerThread(string maxMem, string minMem, string TekkitPath)
{
    try
    {
        TekkitServer.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
        TekkitServer.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-Xmx{0} -Xms{1} -jar \"" + TekkitPath + "\" -nojline nogui", maxMem, minMem);
        TekkitServer.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        TekkitServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        TekkitServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        TekkitServer.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TekkitServer_OutputDataReceived);

        IsStarted = TekkitServer.Start();
        TekkitServerInput = TekkitServer.StandardInput;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}

void TekkitServer_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    /*B*/recordedData.Add(e.Data);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

Where `/*B*/` is a break point, the breakpoint is never activating

Comment: Something else to consider:  It could be writing to StandardError.

Comment: @AustinSalonen checked it not happening it for some reason output is never being handled by my applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the standard output is directed at the console window.
If you need to do something with it, you need to redirect it, hence, you need to set `RedirectStandardOutput = true;` for the event to be fired.

---

Edit: This is my working code (with error handling and logging omitted):

```
public int ExecuteCommand(CommandParameters parameters)
{
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  process.OutputDataReceived += StdOutputHandler;
  process.ErrorDataReceived += StdErrorHandler;
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.FileName = ...;
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = ...;
  process.Start();
  process.BeginErrorReadLine();
  process.BeginOutputReadLine();
  process.WaitForExit(parameters.Timeout);
  return process.ExitCode;
}

private void StdOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outdata)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outdata.Data))
  {
    OutputMessages.Add(outdata.Data);
  }
}
```

Most likely the missing link in your code is the [`BeginOutputReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) that actually gets the handler method on it's way.

Also, I use a fresh `Process` object and that I wait on it to finish it's job, so no interference with previous calls is possible.

Comment: i have tried this and it does not work, hence why i tried turning it off

Comment: It was down to me missing `TekkitServer.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` witch you have not shown so not sure why it would not work on mine without that?

Comment: I can confirm that I do not set the `EnableRaisingEvents` property, and from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) it seems that it only concerns the `Exited` event (which I also don't have). However I do have a `WaitForExit` call that is synchronous. Anyway I think that the output stream is available as soon as the process starts, and not only after it finishes. Glad that you worked out your problem.

Comment: it might have something to do with the Tekkit Server in Java then